Is this considered a running toilet? Recommend fix?
From looking online, this seems much less pronounced with what people usually consider a running toilet, but I still suspect it is?
If this is a running toilet, what’s the fix? Recommended part to replace? That tubing is fairly rigid compared to what I’ve seen googling.
Additional pics of assembly:

https://imgur.com/a/nszEHlz



https://imgur.com/a/fY2mHQC


Video of potential leaking:

https://imgur.com/a/GJ1zcq9


Use your words. Nobody wants to sit and look at a video of your toilet to figure out what you can't be bothered to describe.

You flush, the toilet tank fills up and stops running.  If the flapper/flush valve is leaking the tank level will go down a bit and fill up again.

The fill valve is leaking. It is the valve that allows water to enter the tank.
It appears to be old. You can replace parts in the valve if they can be found, but that can be fruitless.
Fill valves are inexpensive and easy to replace.
While you are at it replace the flapper. That will cure the problem.

So just replaced the fill valve and it’s still leaking. Going to try and replace the flange and see if that helps.

You could not have replaced the fill valve and still have a leak. OR the new valve is far out of adjustment.   Post a pic of the new valve and let us eee the entire tank.

If water is moving from the tank to the bowl (cistern to pan for the UK) without the flush being activated, the toilet is leaking. If water runs from the fill valve into the tank but stops when the tank fills, that's not actually a leak. Your pictures do not show overflow, nor active leaking when full; which indicates that any "leak" from the fill valve is merely filling the tank, not leaking out of it.
If it's overflowing into the overflow tube, the problem is a misadjusted or broken fill valve, and you adjust or replace that.
If it's leaking though the flapper valve (or drum  valve, or other flush valve) you replace the bad part(s) there, ranging from just a rubber seal to a bad valve seat for the more common types.
If you're not sure, put some dye (food coloring, etc.) in the tank and don't flush. If color shows up in the bowl, it's leaking.

Which one is this? https://imgur.com/a/GJ1zcq9

@Paul,  that's the fill valve....it's old replace it.
